# select all dimensions of an ndarray but one

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have an `ndarray` `m` with dimension (2,3,4). I want to select a particular dimension index and sum everything else like this:

```
m[:, 2, :].sum()
```

but I need a function to handle the element selection because the `ndarray` can have different dimensions and the sum should be across various slices. The function would take the dimension (here 0, 1 or 2), and the index (0, 1 or 2 as well) of interest and return `m[:, 2, :].sum()` if the input is (1, 2). If it is (2, 0), I would expect the have the equivalent of `m[:, :, 0].sum()`.

I do not know how to write such a function though, something that would allow me to put the slice ":" into a variable maybe? I have not been able to find a solution so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the slice `:` into a variable with `sl = slice(None, None, None)`. However, numpy has a shorthand for this, [`np.s_[:]`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.s_.html)

Overall then:

```
def sum_axis_i(arr, axis, i):
    idx = (np.s_[:],) * axis + (i,)
    return arr[idx].sum()
```

Note that trailing `:`s are redundant, so we don't bother creating them.

If you use `np.index_exp`, which is very similar to `np.s_`, you can write that:

```
def sum_axis_i(arr, axis, i):
    idx = np.index_exp[:] * axis + np.index_exp[i]
    return arr[idx].sum()
```

Comment: Awesome! I was actually looking at slice too, but I had no idea that ":" could be replaced by slice(None, None, None) or np.s_[:]. This is super convenient. Thanks Eric and MSeifert!

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by dynamically creating a `tuple` of `slice`:

```
def sum_layer_axis(array, layer, axis):
    slicer = tuple(slice(None) if ax != axis else layer for ax in range(array.ndim))
    return np.sum(array[slicer])
```

Just to illustrate how this works consider what is interpreted from the `slice`:

```
class Fun(object):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return item
Fun()[:, 2, :]
# (slice(None, None, None), 2, slice(None, None, None))
```

So we would need to recreate that (but we don't need to specify 3 times the `None`, one is enough). This is possible with a generator expression:

```
tuple(slice(None) if ax != axis else layer for ax in range(array.ndim))
```

so whenever the axis is not the wanted axis just insert the `:` equivalent: `slice(None)` and otherwise insert the specified layer.

To test the result:

```
a = np.arange(3*4*5).reshape((3,4,5))

axis = 1
layer = 2
a[:, layer, :].sum()
# 480
sum_layer_axis(a, layer, axis)
# 480
```

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the most efficient but it should work:

```
m = np.arange(60).reshape((3,4,5))

def my_sum(m, dim, index):
    dims = tuple(i for i in xrange(m.ndim) if i != dim)
    return m.sum(axis=dims)[index]

print my_sum(m,1,2)
print m[:,2,:].sum()
```

Comment: Yep, I was contemplating that same idea but thought there must be something more efficient. The first 2 solutions are exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that swaps the first axis with the input axis and then index with the input index, which will select all elements in context and finally sum all those for the final result. The implementation would be a compact one with [`np.swapaxes`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html) and [`np.sum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html), like so -

```
def sum_axis_index(m, axis, index):    
    return m.swapaxes(0,axis)[index].sum()
```